# What is the BEST way to do the error handling in react using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm working on a React application. The problem that I face every time whether it is an Angular/React/Vue project is error handling during an AJAX request (could be made using Axios or any other AJAX library)

Most of the answers that I find here are just doing the `console.log(error)` inside the `try catch` or `Promise.reject()` method. A real-world application doesn't work like that.

I want to cater to all of the possible errors and show an appropriate message to the user depending upon the type of the error. For example, the error could be:

- A validation error coming from the API.
- Network failed.
- General errors such as *email/password is incorrect.*
- A form that required some data from the API during the GET request but failed due to an error. What now I'll be left is a dead form that is not able to proceed.
- Any other reason that could raise an error.

How can I come to know of all the possible error situations? And importantly, produce them to see how my application responds to each one of them.

Since I'm also developing APIs, please let me know how I should be sending the errors back to the front-end so that it could handle them appropriately.

Currently, my implementation is (which is not good IMO):

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "../../components/AppLink/AppLink";
import AppTextField from "../../components/FormComponents/AppTextField";
import styles from "../../styles/Auth.module.css";
import { Box, Button, Grid, Hidden, InputAdornment, Typography, Collapse  } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Alert, AlertTitle } from '@material-ui/lab';
import EmailSvgIcon from "../../components/Icons/EmailSvgIcon";
import LockSvgIcon from "../../components/Icons/LockSvgIcon";
import LockOpenIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOpen';
import { ROUTE_FORGOT_PASSWORD, ROUTE_REGISTER } from "../../utils/RoutesList";
import AuthBanner from "../../components/AuthBanner/AuthBanner";
import useIsMobile from "../../hooks/useIsMobile";
import * as yup from 'yup';
import axios from '../../axiosConfig';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import { useState } from "react";
import { AlertProps } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { mapApiErrorsToHookForm } from "../../utils/Form";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';

interface FormValues
{
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

interface AlertState
{
    severity : AlertProps["severity"];
    title    : string;
    message  : string;
    show     : boolean;
}

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string()
        .required("Please enter your email")
        .email("Please enter a valid email address"),
    password: yup.string().required("Please enter your password"),
});

const LoginPage = () =>
{
    const formMethods = useForm <FormValues>({
        resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
    });

    const { isSubmitting } = formMethods.formState;
    const isMobile = useIsMobile();

    const [alert, setAlert] = useState <AlertState>({
        severity : undefined,
        title    : "",
        message  : "",
        show     : false,
    });

    const onSubmit = async (formValues: any) =>
    {
        try
        {
            const response = await axios.post("auth/user/login", formValues);
            
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            const exception: AxiosError = error;

            let title = "Error", message: string;

            if (exception.response && exception.response.status === 400)
            {
                message = exception.response.data.message;

                switch (exception.response.data.errorType)
                {
                    case "VALIDATION_ERROR":
                        title = "Incorrect input";
                        
                        let errors = mapApiErrorsToHookForm(exception.response.data.errors)

                        for (let field in errors)
                        {
                            formMethods.setError(field as keyof FormValues, {
                                type: "validation",
                                message: errors[field]
                            });
                        }

                        break;

                    case "ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND":
                        title = "Account not found";
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = exception.message;
            }

            setAlert({
                title,
                message,
                severity: "error",
                show: true
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Grid
                item
                container
                xs={12}
                sm={4}
                direction="column"
                justify="space-between"
                className={styles.bannerGrid}>
                <AuthBanner
                    image="/images/auth/login_banner.jpg"
                    title="Tip"
                    description="The search for housing on this site is 10 times faster"
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item container sm={8} className={styles.contentWrapper}>
                <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" flex={1} paddingX={2} paddingY={2}>
                    <Hidden only="xs">
                        <Box textAlign="right">
                            <Link
                                underline="none"
                                href={ROUTE_REGISTER}
                                color="textPrimary"
                                className={styles.topLink}>
                                Register
                            </Link>
                        </Box>
                    </Hidden>
                    <Box
                        display="flex"
                        flexDirection="column"
                        justifyContent="center"
                        flex={1}
                        maxWidth={500}>
                        <Box marginBottom={3}>
                            <Box marginBottom={1.5}>
                                <Typography variant="h4" className={styles.formTitle}>Login</Typography>
                            </Box>
                            <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">Welcome back!</Typography>
                        </Box>
                        <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
                            <form onSubmit={formMethods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                                <Collapse in={alert.show && !isSubmitting}>
                                    <Box marginBottom={3}>
                                        <Alert
                                            severity={alert.severity}
                                            onClose={() => setAlert({...alert, show: false})}>
                                            <AlertTitle>{alert.title}</AlertTitle>
                                            {alert.message}
                                        </Alert>
                                    </Box>
                                </Collapse>
                                <Box marginBottom={2}>
                                    <AppTextField
                                        name="email"
                                        type="email"
                                        label="Email"
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        fullWidth
                                        InputProps={{
                                            endAdornment: (
                                                <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                    <EmailSvgIcon fontSize="small" />
                                                </InputAdornment>
                                            ),
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Box>
                                <Box marginBottom={2}>
                                    <AppTextField
                                        name="password"
                                        type="password"
                                        label="Password"
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        fullWidth
                                        InputProps={{
                                            endAdornment: (
                                                <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                    <LockSvgIcon fontSize="small" />
                                                </InputAdornment>
                                            ),
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Box>
                                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                    <Grid
                                        item xs={12}
                                        sm={6}>
                                        <Button
                                            type="submit"
                                            variant="contained"
                                            color="primary"
                                            size="large"
                                            endIcon={
                                                isSubmitting
                                                    ? <CircularProgress color="secondary" size={18} />
                                                    : <LockOpenIcon />
                                            }
                                            fullWidth={isMobile}
                                            disabled={isSubmitting}>
                                            Login
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid
                                        item
                                        container
                                        xs={12}
                                        sm={6}
                                        alignItems="center"
                                        justify={isMobile ? "center" : "flex-end"}>
                                        <Link
                                            href={ROUTE_FORGOT_PASSWORD}
                                            color="primary"
                                            className={styles.formLink}>
                                            Forgot Password?
                                        </Link>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </form>
                        </FormProvider>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Grid>
        </>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

For this specific form, I'm sending the `errorType` from the API and based on it, I set the corresponding alert title and message but do I need to do this for every single form?

I know about the interceptors but it won't be able to show the validation message under each of the error field since the `formMethods` won't be able in its context.

Please provide a detailed answer with examples so I can have good understanding about it. Also, don't forget to explain how can I tackle all of the possible error scenarios and handle them.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) of Axios, and handle some error globally like this

```
const axiosInstance = Axios.create({
  baseURL: apiEndpoint,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(undefined, error => {
  const statusCode = error.response ? error.response.status : null;

  if (statusCode === 401) {
    // logout user
  }

  if (statusCode >= 500) {
    // show server error
  }

  if (statusCode === 400) {
    // show bad request error
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Then if you need you can also handle in component level.

Comment: I wrote a detailed question and your answer satisfy a bit. I already know what you wrote but this doesn't answer my question.
"Show bad request error" - Show it where? In a notification? Let's say I want to show it above the form, now what?

Comment: "Show bad request error" It actually depends on your need. Like if I want to show a Mui Snackbar, I will create a parent container where the error component will live. Then with the help of Context API I will show the error component.

Comment: @Mohib how will you update the context API from interceptors functions?

Comment: @Shubham you need to use axios as a hook so that you can use other hooks methods etc inside interceptors. Here is an example:
https://github.com/mbmohib/nudash/blob/main/src/hooks/use-axios.ts